# CSS: Menu is hidden behind other parent menu

Tags: html, css

I have a drop down menu with submenus that are populated from the DB. However, when I resize the screen , and hover over an option, the menu list falls behind another element.

I have browsed the net but to no avail.

Could you guys help?

PS: Was not able to postt an image since SO asks for 10 reputation to post images.

Comment: show us what have you tried. Create some fiddle etc

Comment: As a heads up don't post images on SO without the appropriate code to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

have you triedusing the `z-index` proprety??

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `z-index: 9999`. This ensures the submenu is always on top.

After that set `position:relative;left: <someLeftOfsset>;top:<someTopOffset>` on the submenu.
That will position the submenu relative to its parent by applying an offset on it.

So for example:

```
.subMenu 
{
    z-index: 99999;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 150px; 
}
```